# how to upper case in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I'm new about crystal report. I need to do trim and upper  and the trim about a column and a parameter. My code is :

```
IIF ( {?TypeC} = '', true, 
    IIF (Trim  ( UpperCase({QUERY_ST.TYPE_ELEMEN})) =UpperCase(  Trim  ({?TypeC} )), true, false) )
```

I read this error:

```
string inferred type: string array while application of function TRIM
```

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you find the solution?

The Error comes due to nullable value of the field. So for this you can use with isnull in the above formula

```
if isnull({?TypeC}) or trim({?TypeC}) = "" then
  "No data"
else
  "data: " + UpperCase(trim({?TypeC}))
```